# Signed Java Applets Slower?

Tags: java, html, applet, signed-applet

Do signed java applets load slower than unsigned ones? Is there a 'browser freeze' because the Java VM is checking if the applet is signed properly with a real vendor?

Also, what is up with the 'browser freeze' when an applet is loading. Is it because the Java applet is initializing while the page is loading, because i use the following PHP code to load my applet?

```
<?php
if(!empty($id)){
echo <<< END
<object codetype="application/x-java-applet" type="application/x-java-applet" code="downloader.class" archive="downloader.jar" height="0" width="0" align="center" cache_archive="downloader.jar" initial_focus="true">
<param name="v" value="$id"/>
<param name="u" value="$id"/>
<param name="ua" value="$agent"/>
It appears you do not have Java installed or it is disabled on your system.<br>
Please download it <a href="http://www.java.com/getjava/" class="link" target="_blank">here</a>.
</object>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout("error()",120000);
});
</script>
END;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, signed applet are slower in general.

Regarding freeze problem i recommend to activate Java Console

[How do I enable and view the Java Console?](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml)

Then from the console you would be able to see the trace and understand what kind of problem happens.

My guess is that some exception occurs.